# Creating a python dictionary with preset Keys that return Lists as Values

Tags: python, dictionary

So it turns out my code environment was malfunctioning. The dictionary I was trying to create does actually work after I cleaned things up.

<strike>I'm using python to build a responsive menu that will change depending on another menu's selection. I have a list of items from the first menu that I would like to use as keys in a dictionary, with each key (menu item) returning a specialized list of possible options based on the selection, so that when a user chooses an item from the first menu, the second menu's options will change.</strike>

The first approach I thought of was a dictionary that uses the first menu's list items as the keys which return the options as a list from the specialized dictionary. Unfortunately, constructing this dictionary with preset keys (the list items) and preset values (a list of values) has proven difficult. I have seen several answers on StackOverflow that deal with creating a dictionary of automated numerical keys (so that the final result is (1:['a','b','c']) etc.; but that solution doesn't work, as I'll need the keys themselves to be pre-determined strings. e.g. ('name one': ['a','b','c'], 'name two':['b','c','d'], etc.).

Is there a way to get this kind of thing done? Or is there a more efficient approach that I'm not considering?

UPDATE: To clarify, I **don't** need a literal 'name one', 'name two' with incrementally increasing values as the keys. I have a list of 148 names that I need to use as keys for their individual return values. So the result needs to be a dictionary like this:

```
'John Doe':['a','b','c'],
'Jane Doe':['b','c','d'],
'Mickey Mouse':['a','c','e'], etc.
```

I'm not sure how to go about constructing this, since Python doesn't want to take a list of strings as a dictionary value in a straightforward manner.

Comment: You should go deeper in the part  "Python doesn't want to take a list of strings as a dictionary value" because my tests show that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import inflect
i = inflect.engine()
val=[['a','b','c'],['b','c','d']]
{"name "+i.number_to_words(k):v for (k,v) in list(enumerate(val,1))}
```

Output:

```
{'name one': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'name two': ['b', 'c', 'd']}
```